# ggplot scatterplot points with no fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a scatterplot whose points have no fill (or equivalently, with a transparent fill).

```
# generate some random data for the scatterplot
n <- 5
f <- factor(1:n)
df <- expand.grid(f1 = f, f2 = f)
df <- transform(df, v1 = round(10 * runif(n ** 2)))

# plot the scatterplot
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = f1, y = f2, size = v1, fill = NA))
```

Setting `fill` to `NA` seems logical but did not work. I also tried `NULL` and `""` to no avail.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think you want to play with shape but  may be wrong:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = f1, y = f2, size = v1), shape=1)
```

Or maybe...

```
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = f1, y = f2, size = v1), fill="green", shape=21)
```

if you want to fill a color.

Comment: Thanks! I read the ggplot2 source code; `fill = NA` is the correct way to remove the fill. But, with the default shape being a solid disc, the fill (or lack thereof) could not be seen.

Comment: Yes it does. I was just sharing, for future reference, that there is nothing syntactically wrong with `fill = NA`; it does remove any fill color. Still, it has no effect with the `shape = 19` default (a solid disc) since the "fill" is already part of the shape itself. The terminology is confusing, but is isn't your fault!

Answer (score 11):

In the later versions of ggplot (ggplot2_3.0.0) you can do the following using any shape:

```
    ggplot(df) +
      geom_point(aes(x = f1, y = f2, size = v1, shape = v1)) +
      scale_shape(solid = FALSE)
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that.

Comment: This seems to be a bit unreliable as it appears to only work if you set your `shape` variable of the `geom`, not if you want to use the same shape for all points with a blank `geom_point`. On the other hand, if you are interested in using different shapes for groups in the data, this appears to be the only working solution.